# how to set alignment of views in relative layout using java code in android

Tags: java, android

how to set the alignment of views in the relative layout using java code in android

I know how to do in XML

```
android:layout_alignLeft="@id/button1"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="@id/button2"
```

but, I want to know how to write using java code?
My Problem is to 
I want to align one TextView to right and ImageView to left inside a RelativeLayout.
How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
Button btn = (Button)findviewbyid(R.id.your_button_id)

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, view.getId());

bbtn.setLayoutParams(params);
```

And then do the same for `LEFT_OF`